# Binary XML file line #23 in layout/abc_screen_simple: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout

Tags: android, migration, android-databinding, androidx

[image]

I am upgrading android gradle and migrating to android X. I am getting this runtime error on inflating splash screen.

Edited:
So this project is made for sdk 28 and it's working fine in android pie.
Now I just updated gradle and increased targetSdkVersion to 34, Still getting the same error

let me know if you need more info

Comment: I suffered from same error for 3 days. Did you find solution ???